# How to call jasperReport parameter object that holds another object?

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports

I have been trying to *call jasperReport* parameter object that holds another object like the following example:

```
$P{firstObject}.getSecondObject().getId()
```

but its *not working*. I have no problem accessing simple data types like String

```
$P{firstObject}.getName
```

but I couldn't achieve it with *nested objects*.

Some help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the datasource used?

Comment: @Arasu I am passing my abject as a parameter                                           Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>(); params.put("firstObject", firstObject);                                             JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, params, new JREmptyDataSource());